# Lucene QueryParser Analyzer inconsistency

Tags: lucene, analyzer, query-parser

I have a very simple **Analyzer** that tries to replace forward slashes (/) by spaces. Because **QueryParser** forces me to escape strings with slashes before parsing, I added a **MappingCharFilter** to the analyzer that replaces "\/" with a single space. The analyzer is defined as follows:

```
@Override
protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String field, Reader in) {
    NormalizeCharMap.Builder builder = new NormalizeCharMap.Builder();
    builder.add("\\/", " ");
    Reader mappingFilter = new MappingCharFilter(builder.build(), in);

    Tokenizer tokenizer = new WhitespaceTokenizer(version, mappingFilter);
    return new TokenStreamComponents(tokenizer);
}
```

Then I use this analyzer in the QueryParser to parse a string with dashes:

```
String text = QueryParser.escape("one/two");
QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_48, "f", new MyAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_48));
System.err.println(parser.parse(text));
```

The expected output would be

```
f:one f:two
```

However, I get:

```
f:one/two
```

The puzzling thing is that when I debug the analyzer, it tokenizes the input string correctly, returning two tokens instead of one.

What is going on?

Thanks.

Comment: just so you know, the query parser will treat the text before the analyzer will, so punching in f:foo/bar fill probably end up in a phrase query like f:"foo bar" in the best case scenario, by getting multiple analyzer tokens from a query parser token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple fix. Don't escape the front slash character in the first argument of the builder.add method.

```
builder.add("/", " ");
```